# JavaFX detect if shape has been assigned to a Region/Parent/Node

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, region

as the title inquires is it **possible**?

eg. suppose i have a custom class that extends `Shape`

```
private class CR extends Rectangle{
    public CR(){}
} 
CR cr = new CR(); //normal rectangle
Pane pane = new Pane();// my node who extends region
pane.setPrefSize(100.0,100.0);
pane.setShape(cr); // here is what i am interested in
```

i want to know when `cr` has been set to a `Node`, is there any bindings, or any way i can be notified?

to summarise i have two questions

- is there a way to detect either with bindings or some logic when your custom `Shape` class is being set to a `Region`. ?
- can i get a reference to the `Node`/`Region`/`Parent` ?

Edit:

i am not suppose/ i do not have - access to the pane or Node that is going to set its shape as the custom shape -(implementing my Shape), something like my class is a library/wrapper.

also my custom `Shape` is not extending `Rectangle` but just for sample sake but i am extending `Path` with extends `Shape` to draw a complex `Shape`

*if its possible i will put a bounty of 300 as gift*

Comment: Every node has a [`parentProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#parentProperty). Can you just register a listener with that, or am I missing something?

Comment: yes i tested getParent() but it tends out to be null, well, the flip side of this is i am not suppose to have access to pane or Node that will set its shape as the custom shape, do you get me Sir?@James_D

Comment: wondering why you want it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, but does:

```
cr.parentProperty().addListener((obs, oldParent, newParent) -> {

    System.out.println("Parent changed from "+oldParent+" to "+newParent);

    if (newParent != null) {
        // do whatever you need here...
    }
});
```

do what you need?

Comment: sorry for the delay Sir James_D it does not do nothing, actually, what i mean is you can change the shape of a Node using the children of shape class, and i am extending a shape class child and i want that child to be notified if it is altering the shape of a node at the moment so i can play with that Node to meet certain shape changes

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean check = pane.contains(cr .getX(),cr .getY());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sir Fevly but in my custom shape class how do i get a reference to the pane, that was just some example code, but i do not have reference to pane, only my class, and i need a way to be notified when my shape has been assigned to a region, and also get a reference to it

Comment: why not just passing `pane` reference to  CR's constructor as argument?

Comment: nice, but what if the implementer passe `pane1` to the constructor and set's the shape to rather  `pane2` ? my class will be violated, the reason being is i need the pane or node who shape has been set using my custom shape class to emit some properties as its not just a normal rectangle but rather a complex shape and not having that means my its useless, is it possible? btw?

Comment: that's kinda hard (perhaps I don't know how to do that ) since your Rectangle is not added through .getChildren().add()  instead of pane.setShape() so parent of the shape (get shape's parent) will be just null.